# Estéreo Visão no Matlab

Tags: matlab, visão-computacional

Olá!!
Estou tentando executar um algoritmo em Matlab que usa apenas funções próprias do Matlab. O programa deveria inicialmente fazer a calibração das câmeras, extrair os seus parâmetros e gerar um mapa de disparidade através de duas imagens retificadas com os parâmetros obtidos na calibração. Contudo quando eu executo o programa gera um erro que eu não sei como resolver. Eu uso a versão 2015a com a toolbox "Computer Vision System" instalada e para a calibração estou usando um tabuleiro quadriculado. Abaixo está o algoritmo que estou usando:

```
%Carrega os pares de imagens para calibração
ParesdeImagens = 11;
arquivoImagens1 = cell(1,ParesdeImagens);
arquivoImagens2 = cell(1,ParesdeImagens);
imagemDir = fullfile('C:','Users','carlo','Documents','Iniciacao','Matlab','Principal');
for i = 1:ParesdeImagens
   arquivoImagens1{i} = fullfile(imagemDir,  sprintf('left%02d.jpg', i));
   arquivoImagens2{i} = fullfile(imagemDir,  sprintf('right%02d.jpg', i));
end

%Realiza a detecção dos cantos no tabuleiro
[imagePoints, boardSize, pairsUsed] = detectCheckerboardPoints(arquivoImagens1, arquivoImagens2);

%Exibe os pontos identificados da camera esquerda
arquivoImagens1=arquivoImagens1(pairsUsed);
figure;
for i= 1:numel(arquivoImagens1)
   I= imread(arquivoImagens1{i});
   subplot(3,4,i);
   imshow(I);
   hold on;
   plot(imagePoints(:,1,i,1),imagePoints(:,2,i,1),'*-g');
end

%Exibe os pontos identificados da camera direita
arquivoImagens2=arquivoImagens2(pairsUsed);
figure;
for i= 1:numel(arquivoImagens2)
   I= imread(arquivoImagens2{i});
   subplot(3,4,i);
   imshow(I);
   hold on;
   plot(imagePoints(:,1,i,2),imagePoints(:,2,i,2),'*-g');
end

%Computa as coordenadas reais do tabuleiro  
squareSize = 29; % milimetros
worldPoints = generateCheckerboardPoints(boardSize, squareSize);

%Computa os parâmetros estéreos  
stereoParams = estimateCameraParameters(imagePoints, worldPoints);

%Avalia a precisão da calibração
figure;
showReprojectionErrors(stereoParams);

% Lê um par de imagens
I1 = imread('esquerda.jpg');
I2 = imread('direita.jpg');

%Retifica as imagens
[J1, J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2, stereoParams);

%Exibe as imagens antes da retificação
figure;
imshow(stereoAnaglyph(I1, I2));
title('Antes da Retificacao');

%Exibe as imagens depois da retificação
figure;
imshow(stereoAnaglyph(J1, J2));
title('Depois da Retificacao');

%Gera o mapa de disparidade
disparityMap = disparity(rgb2gray(J1), rgb2gray(J2));
figure;
imshow(disparityMap, [0, 64]);
colormap('jet');
colorbar;
title('Mapa de Disparidade');
```

Quando eu executo o programa recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in vision.internal.calibration.CameraParametersImpl/getValidBounds (line 883)
        if isempty(coder.target) && (left > right || top > bot)

Error in vision.internal.calibration.CameraParametersImpl/computeUndistortBounds (line 785)
                [xBounds, yBounds] = getValidBounds(this, undistortedMask, ...

Error in vision.internal.calibration.StereoParametersImpl/computeOutputBounds (line 371)
        [xBoundsUndistort1, yBoundsUndistort1] = ...

Error in vision.internal.calibration.StereoParametersImpl/computeRectificationParameters (line 271)
        [xBounds, yBounds] = computeOutputBounds(this, imageSize, ...

Error in vision.internal.calibration.StereoParametersImpl/rectifyStereoImagesImpl (line 190)
            [H1, H2, Q, xBounds, yBounds] = ...

Error in rectifyStereoImages (line 99)
[rectifiedImage1, rectifiedImage2] = rectifyStereoImagesImpl(stereoParams, ...

Error in new_project (line 55)
[J1, J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1, I2, stereoParams);
```

Neste caso, foram reconhecidos corretamente os cantos de todas as imagens de ambos os pares, e foi estimado um erro de 4 pixels. Para a aquisição de imagens eu usei uma distância de 10 cm entre as câmeras e me certifiquei que ambas estavam paralelas e alinhadas corretamente. Todas as imagens foram obtidas por uma câmera de celular ( Nokia Lumia 520 ).

Aqui está uma imagem do tabuleiro que usei para calibrar o par estéreo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém tiver alguma idéia do que pode estar acontecendo e puder me auxiliar seria de grande ajuda!

Obrigado.